# how to integrate Windows 8 SDK with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, winapi, visual-c++-2012

According to the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx

> By removing the command-line build environment, the Windows SDK no longer ships the following components:
>
> Windows SDK Platform Toolset
>
> Visual C++ Compilers and C Runtime (CRT)
>
> Windows SDK Configuration Tool

If the Windows SDK Configuration Tool is removed, is there an easy way to update the paths? I realize I can manually update Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props (and other property pages), but I was hoping for an easier way than having to hunt around for everything. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 already comes with the Windows 8.0 SDK and is used whenever you build with the "v110" platform toolset. As long as you installed VS 2012 Express for Windows Desktop, or VS 2012 Pro or higher edition, you have the full Windows 8.0 SDK. And actually with the VS 2012 Update 1, you have the Windows 7.1A SDK as well when using the "v110_xp" Platform Toolset.

Similarly if you have Visual Studio 2013 you have the Windows 8.1 SDK.

The 'manual' part comes in when you want to use the Windows 8.x SDK with Visual Studio 2010, or the Windows 8.1 SDK with Visual Studio 2012. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/15/visual-studio-2012-and-windows-8-0-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx) blog post.